# Add widgets to a ScrollArea

Tags: qt, layout, qwidget, qscrollarea

I am creating a window dimanica to the downloads list.
But the scrollbar does not work and the "widgets children" are "cut".

Where can I be wrong? Thanks.

**Source:**

```
    QWidget *central = new QWidget;
    QScrollArea *scroll = new QScrollArea;
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(scroll);
    scroll->setWidget(central);
    scroll->setWidgetResizable(true);

    int i=0;
    while(i<10){
        QWidget *p1 = new QWidget;
        QHBoxLayout *hl = new QHBoxLayout(p1);
        QLabel *label1 = new QLabel("test");
        QLabel *label2 = new QLabel("0%");
        hl->addWidget(label1);
        hl->addWidget(label2);
        layout->addWidget(p1);
        i++;
    }

    QMainWindow *w = new QMainWindow;
    w->setGeometry(50,50,480,320);
    w->setCentralWidget(scroll);
    w->show();
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to make a list. Maybe have a look at `QListWidget` or the `QListView` and `QAbstractListModel` duo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found your mistake, you should set `layout` to widget `central` not to `scroll`:

```
QWidget *central = new QWidget;
QScrollArea *scroll = new QScrollArea;
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(central);
scroll->setWidget(central);
scroll->setWidgetResizable(true);
```

EDITED:

Your labels already take all available space, if you noticed, `label1` begins at left border ends in the middle, where `label2` starts and ends at the right border. If I understood you correctly, you want `label1` to take all the space available, while `label2` with percents to take only what space is needed, no more?

Read about `QSizePolicy` class and use `setSizePolicy()` on your labels. Try to insert this line right after label2 declaration:

```
QLabel *label2 = new QLabel("0%");
label2->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy::Maximum,QSizePolicy::Maximum);
```

And add line `layout->addStretch();` right before `QMainWindow *w = new QMainWindow;`

Comment: Nice, But has the only stretch to Horizontal?

Comment: you want to keep geometry (50,50,480,320) and stretch labels take all horizontal space?

Comment: Yes, I want each item (Widget child) occupy all space horizontally (horizontal only). Could you help me? Thank you for your attention. No need to be fixed height or width. The window can be resized.

Comment: i don't understant, what you want to achive, in my test app, all works perfectly. Why don't you post screenshot with your current situation, and how you want to change it

Comment: Maybe if you replace `while(i<10)` by `while(i<3)` you will see the problem. Screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CRVhq.png

Comment: add line `layout->addStretch();` before `QMainWindow *w = new QMainWindow;`